# Distribute on Google Play to specific people

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to distribute the beta for my Android App to 10,000 specific people that signed up for the prerelease via the Play Store for free. Keeping in mind that the app will eventually be a paid application, is this specificity possible?

Comment: I don't think you can distribute to specific users via Google Play. you might consider third-party distribution services like TestFlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has licensing enabled, you can add the people who should get it for free in a "whitelist" with their google play account , so that the app would appear as bought from the market. (i know it is possible but never did it... just google it)

After that you can distribute the apk through email (try http://thebetafamily.com/supersend/ ) 
and for the previously added accounts the licensing check will pass, and for other users the licensing check will fail if they did not bought the app from market.

This was just a suggestion, never had to do something like this , but thought this might help !

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Google Play does not allow paid application to be given away for free (minimum price is ~$1).
You can do it other way:
Publish your application free
For premium features request some in-app payment
Implement in your application some piece of code to unlock premium features to specific users. 
I have found a library for it: https://code.google.com/p/remoteunlockerlib/ But not sure if it works at this moment :)